# How do I create a functional app icon in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Launcher (Universal Gcode Sender)

Tags: launcher

I am a Noobie making an attempt to get away from Windows, however, I am struggling with what should be a relatively simple task.

I downloaded Universal Gcode Sender (CNC control software).  I am able to get the program to work by opening the terminal and typing the bin file name:

```
./ugsplatform
```

However, I would like to have an app in the Ubuntu Launcher for this purpose. I have spent hours searching for a solution, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

The .desktop file path is as follows:

```
/home/bogen/.local/share/applications/ugsplatform.desktop
```

The contents of the .desktop file are as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=UGS Platform
Comment=UGS Platform is the next generation of Universal Gcode Sender.
GenericName=UGS Platform
Exec=/home/bogen/programfiles/ugsp2/bin/ugsplatform
Type=Application
Icon=/home/bogen/programfiles/ugsp2/ugs_icon.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
```

The path to the binary file is as follows:

```
/home/bogen/ProgramFiles/UGSP2/bin/ugsplatform
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Please keep in mind that I am a complete noob.

I tried the suggestions made by @heynnema and still was not able to get it to work.  I think it has something to do with incorrect paths.

Comment: That's not what my answer instructs you to do. `~/.usr/share/applications/ugsplatform.desktop` is certainly not the correct path. Follow my instructions. Also add a path for the icon.

Comment: When you get my answer to work, please remember to return here and accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry.  I very much appreciate your help, but I tried it again exactly as you stated with no luck.  I click on the icon and it doesn't open the program.  I will keep messing with it. It might be my "icon" line.  I need to find an icon to put in the folder.

Comment: You have to place the .desktop file in the location that I gave you. Then the Super key will find it, and as long as the path to the ugsplatform binary is correct, it should work. Even if you don't complete the Icon= line, it'll still give a generic icon, until you get the correct path there. The icon probably already exists in one of the ugsplatform sub-folders.

Comment: I tried to locate the .desktop file through the file manager.  I am questioning if it has actually been created.  Do i need to close out the terminal with some special code?

Comment: You created your file in a hidden directory in your home folder called .usr. In Nautilus (file manager) you have to type control-h to see hidden folders/files. Once you find the file, just delete it and start my instructions over. There's nothing to close out the `terminal` once you quit `gedit`. Just close the window.

Comment: Still no success.  I found the .desktop file in home/bogen/.local/share/applications/ugsplatform.  The .desktop file gave an error message when I clicked on it "untrusted application launcher"  Also, when I use the Super key to search for it it doesn't show up.  I have triple checked all my spelling and the location of the bin file.  I can still type the Bin file ./ugsplatfom into the terminal to get it to work, but nothing through the Launcher.  I am drawing at straws here, maybe I should have  unzipped the file into a different directory?

Comment: Make sure the file is named ugsplatform.desktop. Then, `Get Properties` and go to the Permissions tab, and enable the "Allow executing file as program" checkbox. Then it should work.

Comment: I did that.  It gave me the same error message but this time with the option to "trust" it.  After proceeding an new error message pops up "There was an error launching the application"  Thanks again for all the help, if you want to give up on me I would understand.

Comment: Go to the directory where the ugsplatform binary file is. Select the icon and right-click COPY. Then open `gedit` and do a paste. Show me the "file" line. Also, edit your question and show me the current contents of the .desktop file.

Comment: /home/bogen/.local/share/applications/ugsplatform.desktop

Comment: That path is fine. But I asked for the path to the ugsplatform binary file. I also needed to see the current contents of your .desktop file.

Comment: Sorry, here is the path to the binary:  /home/bogen/ProgramFiles/UGSP2/bin/ugsplatform

Comment: I've updated my answer with the paths provided by you. It should work now, assuming that the paths are correct. Upper/lower case is important. Report back.

Comment: It works! :) Thank you.  I am so exited and I learned a lot on the journey.  Thank  you!!!!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `terminal` app, type the following, to create a new .desktop file:

`gedit ~/.local/share/applications/ugsplatform.desktop`

Copy/paste the following text:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=UGS Platform
Comment=UGS Platform is the next generation of Universal Gcode Sender.
GenericName=UGS Platform
Exec=/home/bogen/ProgramFiles/UGSP2/bin/ugsplatform
Type=Application
Icon=/home/bogen/ProgramFiles/UGSP2/ugs_icon.png
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

Make sure the file is named `ugsplatform.desktop`. Then, Get Properties on the newly created file, and go to the Permissions tab, and enable the "Allow executing file as program" checkbox.

Hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and type `ugs`.

Comment: I still was not able to get it to work.  I think it has something to do with incorrect paths.  I tried you suggestions, but also the following:

Answer (score 0):

- Downloaded it from [here](https://winder.github.io/ugs_website/download/)
- `~/Downloads$ unzip UniversalGcodeSender.zip`
- `mv ~/Downloads/UniversalGcodeSender.jar ~/test/`
- `chmod +x ~/test/UniversalGcodeSender.jar`
- Checked it could be launched by `java -jar ~/test/UniversalGcodeSender.jar`
- Created .desktop shortcut: `vim.tiny ~/.local/share/applications/ugsplatform.desktop`

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Version=1.0
  Type=Application
  Name=UGS Platform
  Comment=Universal G-Code Sender is a Java based, cross platform G-Code sender, compatible with GRBL and TinyG/g2core. Use this program to run a GRBL or TinyG/g2core controlled CNC machine.
  Exec=/home/user/test/usgplatform.sh
  Icon=firefox
  Path=/home/user/test
  Terminal=false
  StartupNotify=false
  Categories=Utility
  ```
- Created `~/test/usgplatform.sh` script to launch:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  /usr/bin/java -jar ~/test/UniversalGcodeSender.jar
  ```
- `chmod +x ~/test/usgplatform.sh`
- `chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/ugsplatform.desktop`

Application started from menu.

Comment: Thanks Gryu for responding. I am happy to report @heynnema solved my problem before I attempted your solution.